# Сделать взаимосвязь ccылки с value select option

Tags: javascript, jquery

Прошу помощи. Нужно сделать взаимосвязь ссылки `(a)` c select option.
Сейчас работает при клике `a.select-change` меняется option, но мне нужно сделать так, чтобы этой ссылке еще добавлялся класс `a.selected` из соответствующего option selected="selected".

```js
(function($) {
  $('.select-change').click(function() {
    $('#orderby').val($(this).data('val')).trigger('change');
  })
})(jQuery);
```

```css
a {
  padding:10px;
  color:green;
}
a.selected {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="order_by_wr">

  <a data-role="button" data-val="menu_order" class="select-change" id="btna">Name</a>
  <a data-role="button" data-val="popularity" class="select-change" id="btnb">Popular</a>
  <a data-role="button" data-val="price-desc" class="select-change" id="btnc">Price</a>
 

  <form class="woocommerce-ordering" method="get">
    <select name="orderby" class="orderby" id="orderby">
      <option value="menu_order" selected="selected">Name</option>
      <option value="popularity">Popular</option>
      <option value="price-desc">Price</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> но мне нужно сделать так, чтобы этой ссылке еще добавлялся класс a.selected

Вызовите в обработчике `onclick` `$(this).addClass('selected')`. А, чтобы удалить старое выделение предварительно вызовите

```js
$('.select-change').removeClass('selected');
```

```js
(function($) {
  $('.select-change').click(function() {
    $('.select-change').removeClass('selected');
    $('#orderby').val(
      $(this).addClass('selected').data('val')
    ).trigger('change');
  })
})(jQuery);
```

```css
a {
  padding: 10px;
  color: green;
}
a.selected {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="order_by_wr">

  <a data-role="button" data-val="menu_order" class="select-change" id="btna">Name</a>
  <a data-role="button" data-val="popularity" class="select-change" id="btnb">Popular</a>
  <a data-role="button" data-val="price-desc" class="select-change" id="btnc">Price</a>


  <form class="woocommerce-ordering" method="get">
    <select name="orderby" class="orderby" id="orderby">
      <option value="menu_order" selected="selected">Name</option>
      <option value="popularity">Popular</option>
      <option value="price-desc">Price</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но немного не то...
Нужно, чтобы класс добавлялся к ссылке .order_by_wr a.select-change
https://jsfiddle.net/y6byfxzs/3/

Comment: @OsadchiyYuriy Что не то?

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы ссылка выделялась соответствено выбранному select-у

Comment: @OsadchiyYuriy т.е. выделять кликнутую ссылку? `$(this).addClass('selected')`

Comment: Спасибо. Да, именно так, но еще бы сделать так, чтобы класс удалялся, при клике на другую ссылку.

Comment: @OsadchiyYuriy отредактировал еще раз

Comment: Спасибо большое. К сожалению, рейтинг не позволяет  поднять рейтинг ответа.